# Git patch with multiple commits, and the last doesn’t get applied

Tags: git

I have 2 repositories and am trying to use patches to move changes from one to the other. Following is the scenario. There is a commit (`f31541e`) that changes contents of 3 files. Then the last commit (top of the log, `b546664`) deletes one of the files, c.txt.

```
$ git log                                                                       
**commit b54666405a5126e6efcb8b605b3bb0182200f258** (HEAD -> develop, origin/develop
)                                                                               
Author: Andy Whelan                                         
Date:   Tue Feb 25 12:31:24 2020 -0500                                                                                                                 
    Deleted c.txt                                     
**commit f31541e1b6f417deab23e38bab25f854ac45ade6** (origin/patch-delete-c, origin/p
atch-branch-src-us1, patch-delete-c, patch-branch-src-us1)                      
Author: Andy Whelan                                         
Date:   Tue Feb 25 11:00:49 2020 -0500                                                         
    Modified all 3 files.                                          
**commit 32b12065cfa3aa25f07c2698197788792c55b99d** (origin/master, master)         
Author: Andy Whelan                                         
Date:   Tue Feb 25 08:39:54 2020 -0500                                          
    Adding a.txt, b.txt, c.txt
```

I’m creating a single patch file like follows:

```
git format-patch -2 b54666405a5126e6efcb8b605b3bb0182200f258 --stdout > can.patch
```

The patch file (below) has the newest change (the deleted file) at the bottom and the other at the top. Following is some of this file, I have commented out the part where text in 3 files is changed, because that works (//content changes 3 files, this works).The trouble I'm having is that c.txt is not removed, like it should be. The text changes in the 3 files are applied. But the file deletion is not. Anyone have any idea what I might be doing wrong?

```
From f31541e1b6f417deab23e38bab25f854ac45ade6 Mon Sep 17 00:00:00 2001
From: Me <me@someplace.com>
Date: Tue, 25 Feb 2020 11:00:49 -0500
Subject: [PATCH 1/2] patch modifies all 3 files

---
//content changes 3 files, this works
-- 
2.20.1.windows.1


From b54666405a5126e6efcb8b605b3bb0182200f258 Mon Sep 17 00:00:00 2001
From: Me <me@someplace.com>
Date: Tue, 25 Feb 2020 12:31:24 -0500
Subject: [PATCH 2/2] applied patch-delete-c

---
 c.txt | 2 --
 1 file changed, 2 deletions(-)
 delete mode 100644 c.txt

diff --git a/c.txt b/c.txt
deleted file mode 100644
index 1a7ca5c..0000000
--- a/c.txt
+++ /dev/null
@@ -1,2 +0,0 @@
-this is file c
-add a line to c
\ No newline at end of file
-- 
2.20.1.windows.1
```

Comment: How are you *applying* this single patch file?

Comment: Hi torek. Just doing the following: $ git apply can.patch

Comment: OK, well, that's the problem: `git apply` applies *one* patch, and you have *two* patches. You must split the two patches into one-at-a-time and apply each one. Note, however, that if your two patches are in *mailbox format*, i.e., separated by `From` lines, as they are here, you can use `git am`, where A M stands for Apply Mailbox patches. `git am` splits the mailbox file into multiple patches and calls `git apply` on each one.

Comment: The `git format-patch` command will generate mailbox-format files, or will generate individual patches, depending on the options you use when you run it.

Comment: Huh, I can't choose torek's answer as the correct one? I can only flag that it adds something useful?

Comment: That's because it's a comment, not an answer. Did not have time to write up a proper answer...

Comment: Well thanks anyhow. You comment was all I needed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See torek's comment above about using

```
git am <patchfilename>
```

That's the correct answer.